# How to create a Maven project that can be imported as an Android project

Tags: android, maven-3, m2eclipse

I am a fan of Maven and love the freedom it gives me and my fellow programmers when collaborating on a project. I consider myself to have a fairly good understanding of Maven and its pom as well as the command line goals.

Now we are starting to create an android test project to test our Android software in an automatic way. We have no problems doing this from within the eclipse environment and the test suite is now up and running.

However, its time to include more programmers into this project and therefore we want to be able to clone this project from our git repository, run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, import it into a fresh eclipse (of course with android-sdk and what not) and run the tests as is expected.

We stumble over the hurdle that the project doesn't become an Android Test Project within eclipse thus it is not possible to run Android JUnit on any of its classes.

The main question: How do we make the project become an Android Test Project from the terminal window after it has been cloned from Git?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add android nature to the project by adding it in the .project file and then opening eclipse again.

```
<nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
```

You can create an empty android test project, and then compare it's .project file with your project's.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely test and get back to you.

Comment: I've tested and it didn't solve the issue for me, forgot to comment back.